# 405 Error when using Google Apps Script to make Post/Put calls using Spotify API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, spotify

I am trying to do a PUT and DELETE request to the Spotify API using Google Apps Script. However when I do this I get the error: '405 Not Allowed'.

I am really puzzled as to why this is because I am able to make a GET request ok to the same resource, and I am also able to do these PUT and DELETE requests fine in programs like Paw and Postman, but when I do it in Google Apps Script I get the 405 error. This is my current code:

```
var authorisation = "Bearer "+accessToken;

var getUrl = baseURL+'v1/users/'+user+'/playlists/'+playlist+'/tracks';

var replaceOptions = {
      "method":"put",
      "contentType":"application/json",
      "payload":JSON.stringify({"uris": ["spotify:track:4UaGt8uW0srvzFZAwKCumD","spotify:track:5QmvryaxUQyXyFMljdgOPD","spotify:track:5NFNxnghrwogF3H6Pj66f6"]}),
      "headers":{"Authorization":authorisation},
      'muteHttpExceptions':true
    };

  var replaceResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getUrl, replaceOptions);

  Logger.log(replaceResponse.getAllHeaders());
  Logger.log(replaceResponse.getContentText());
  Logger.log(replaceResponse.getResponseCode());
```

I would really appreciate some insight as to what is going on. FYI this is the original endpoint documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/replace-playlists-tracks/).

Comment: Do yo try to remove your JSON.Stringify to keep the json in your payload directly ?

Comment: Yes, and I even copied and pasted the working json string from postman into the payload

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this ended up being a stupid error. I somehow ended up using the base URL from the authentication endpoint of Spotify and not the API endpoint.

I should have posted the full code in my question!

If anyone else runs into this silly issue by mistake, the base URL of authentication is: https://accounts.spotify.com

whereas the api base url is: https://api.spotify.com

Point of learning; just because a lot of API's have one standard URL endpoint not all of them do! And, never overlook the simple things.